# mysql select query help -- ORDER BY

Tags: sql, mysql, database, union

I'm trying to construct a select query where it will take all the columns of 4 tables and then order and display the results by the column 'name' (the same in all tables).  I'm still learning the ropes of MySQL.

I'm finding that because the columns share the name 'name', only the results from the last table are displayed.  Is there a way of performing this query which retains all the data from all the tables?

Should I use different column names?  It seems easier to share one name since it is the same information in each.

```
SELECT * FROM table_one, table_two, table_three, table_four ORDER BY...
```

The four tables not joined, and the structure is different... Some column names are shared (which it looks like I should fix, I still can at this point), but each has a different amount of columns.

Thank you!

Comment: are these 4 tables with the same structure?

Comment: No, the four tables not joined and the structure is different... 

Some column names are shared (which it looks like I should fix, I still can at this point), but each has a different amount of columns.

Comment: You are incorrect, in your query the tables are joined; they are  cross joined. This is almost certainly not what you want based on what you wrote. This is also why the implicit join is a poor practice and should not be used.

Answer (score 3):

If there's no relationship between the four tables, use `UNION`s instead:

```
SELECT a.name
  FROM TABLE_ONE a
UNION
SELECT b.name
  FROM TABLE_TWO b
UNION
SELECT c.name
  FROM TABLE_THREE c
UNION
SELECT d.name
  FROM TABLE_FOUR d
ORDER BY name
```

There's two options here - `UNION` is slower, because it will remove duplicates - the final list will be a unique list of names.  `UNION ALL` is faster because it doesn't remove duplicates.

To get the columns from the tables as well, use:

```
SELECT a.*,
       b.*,
       c.*,
       d.*
  FROM (SELECT a.name
          FROM TABLE_ONE a
        UNION
        SELECT b.name
          FROM TABLE_TWO b
        UNION
        SELECT c.name
          FROM TABLE_THREE c
        UNION
        SELECT d.name
          FROM TABLE_FOUR d) x
LEFT JOIN TABLE_ONE a ON a.name = x.name
LEFT JOIN TABLE_TWO b ON b.name = x.name
LEFT JOIN TABLE_THREE c ON c.name = x.name
LEFT JOIN TABLE_FOUR d ON d.name = x.name
```

Comment: This works perfectly yet only retrieves the name column.  I'm trying to retrieve all columns (or selected columns) as well so I can echo them along with the name column.  In other words, I want the list sorted by name, but have other columns (description, start_time) appearing as well...

I should have been more clear on this... but this is excellent!

Comment: @johnny_n: Updated, but you're going to get a lot of null columns, and likely some duplicates depending on how much data you have.

Comment: @OMG Ponies -- thank you, and I appreciate the warning.  Perhaps a better way is to query only certain columns... I'm sure I can make that work.  Definite learning curve here! ;-)

Comment: Actually, the edited version doesn't seem to work -- it leaves me where I started with 'names' overwritten.  At least the output is the same, I get the results of the last table only.

Comment: @johnny_n: I don't see how you can only be getting the values of the last table, unless the majority of records exist in the last table.  Frankly, it's a really poor setup - there could be duplicates in any of the tables which will inflate the records.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: every table has only one record, and there are two in the last table (table_four in the above example).  I don't believe the duplicates should be an issue as all records are added by the site admin, not users.  I'll investigate a bit further... thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should use different column names, but to get all data also you can write quesries like this:

```
SELECT table_one.* t1, table_two.* t2, table_three.* t3, table_four.* t4 FROM table_one, table_two, table_three, table_four ORDER BY...
```

Answer (score 0):

johnny_n,

You should use

```
 SELECT name as name1, name as name2, name as name3 etc...
```

Obviously you need to use the correct syntax, but using the AS keyword, will allow you to use the key you want in your query.

Comment: You need table aliases, otherwise you'll get name collision errors because there is a `name` column in each of the tables.

Answer (score 0):

If they all share the same `name`'s....

```
SELECT * 
    FROM table_one 
LEFT JOIN
    table_two USING(name)
LEFT JOIN
    table_three USING(name)
LEFT JOIN
    table_four USING(name)
ORDER BY name
```